# How to access single elements in a table in R

Tags: r, indexing

How do I grab elements from a table in [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29)?

My *data* looks like this:

```
         V1     V2
1      12.448 13.919
2      22.242  4.606
3      24.509  0.176
```

etc...

I basically just want to grab elements individually. I'm getting confused with all the R terminology, like vectors, and I just want to be able to get at the individual elements.

Is there a function where I can just do like `data[v1][1]` and get the element in row 1 column 1?

Comment: Try reading the manual: [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Index-vectors) and [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Index-matrices).

Comment: I looked at both links prior to posting, I did not come across the notation. described in the answer.

Comment: Don't see why this was voted down. Its a well formed question with a sound answer.

Comment: (I downvoted.) I agree that it is well formed and sound, but it is very basic. If you had said "I read the help page on indexing (`?Extract`) ...", or "I read section 2.7 of the introduction to R on selecting subsets of a data set ..." or had otherwise demonstrated effort to solve the problem yourself, I would have been more charitable.  (I see that you have now said this in the comments.)  I am just worried that we're going to get overwhelmed with basic indexing questions ...  If you edit (so that I can), I'll reverse my downvote.

Comment: it's a data frame, not a table.

Comment: @OriolPrat : It's not clear what it is from simply the print output. The default `print` function does not allow one to determine whether it is a dataframe, matrix, or R table. All three of those structures allow character margin labels.Admittedly data.frame is the most likely since the `read.table` function would auto-assign column names with "V" followed by a digit or digits.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try

```
data[1, "V1"]  # Row first, quoted column name second, and case does matter
```

Further note: Terminology in discussing R can be crucial and sometimes tricky. Using the term "table" to refer to that structure leaves open the possibility that it was either a 'table'-classed, or a 'matrix'-classed, or a 'data.frame'-classed object. The answer above would succeed with any of them, while @BenBolker's suggestion below would only succeed with a 'data.frame'-classed object.

There is a ton of free introductory material for beginners in R: *[CRAN: Contributed Documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html)*

Comment: or `data[["V1"]][1]` (closer to the original question)

Comment: read table using `read.cv` and when I try: `dat[["V1"]][1]` I get this
`[1] 5042951
54 Levels: 11054 1156785) 1157947) 1159014) 1166898) 1174855) ... src,trg,sp_len,hops` how do I get just `5042951`?

Comment: @sAguinaga You have a factor variable. The `as.character()`-function should be wrapped around dat[['V1']] to pull out the factor values. Then use `[1]` to pick the first one. Anyone reading these comments  again should understand the Ben Bolker's strategy is effective for dataframes only and the logic is pick a full column first and then get the first item in it. My suggestion will succeed for both matrices and dataframes. It's not possible in this case to determine whether the original data is a dataframe or a matrix object.

Comment: Just for what it's worth, R is full of unusual syntax.There are plenty of programmers who are used to indexing like `foo[y][x]`, and said programmers may be able to get quite far in R before hitting a stumbling block like discovering that this double subscript notation doesn't do what they expect. It's not exactly the sort of thing that's easy to google when you're thinking in terms of another language and don't know what this is called, and therefore Stack Overflow is a reasonable place to ask.

Comment: The use of "[" with two index arguments separated by a comma is used for both dataframe and matrix access. I find it hard to believe that this is not covered very early in any sensible introduction to R. If someone is coming to R from another language and not reading any introductory material, then I think asking on SO without looking at their choice of the many Fine Manuals  first deserves to be discouraged. (I do agree that searching for basic indexing syntax on Google or SO might not be easy, but that's why some self-study from a printed introduction is preferred.)

Answer (score 22):

`?"["` pretty much covers the various ways of accessing elements of things.

Under usage it lists these:

```
x[i]
x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]
x[[i, exact = TRUE]]
x[[i, j, ..., exact = TRUE]]
x$name
getElement(object, name)

x[i] <- value
x[i, j, ...] <- value
x[[i]] <- value
x$i <- value
```

The second item is sufficient for your purpose

Under `Arguments` it points out that with `[` the arguments `i` and `j` can be numeric, character or logical

So these work:

```
data[1,1]
data[1,"V1"]
```

As does this:

```
data$V1[1]
```

and keeping in mind a data frame is a list of vectors:

```
data[[1]][1]
data[["V1"]][1]
```

will also both work.

So that's a few things to be going on with. I suggest you type in the examples at the bottom of the help page one line at a time (yes, actually type the whole thing in one line at a time and see what they all do, you'll pick up stuff very quickly and the typing rather than copypasting is an important part of helping to commit it to memory.)

Comment: So it's `?"["`... I was trying things like `?[` or `?[]`, but I kept receiving `Error: unexpected '[' in "?["`. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, you have to quote anything that's either not plain alpha-numerics or is a keyword (e.g. you also need to quote *if* and *for*, for example -- `?"if"` and `?"for"` not `?if` or `?for`). It doesn't hurt to quote even when it's not required.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not so perfect as above ones, but I guess this is what you were looking for.

```
data[1:1,3:3]    #works with positive integers
data[1:1, -3:-3] #does not work, gives the entire 1st row without the 3rd element
data[i:i,j:j]    #given that i and j are positive integers
```

Here indexing will work from 1, i.e,

```
data[1:1,1:1]    #means the top-leftmost element
```