# How transform all the variables of a data.table of one row to single values

Tags: r, variables, datatable, transform, wrangle

I created DT putting the values in a table:

```
a <- 2
b <- 20
c <- 0.3
DT <- data.table(a, b, c)
```

let's assume that I have only the DT generated.
How can from DT generate a, b, c (single values)

Thanks and best regards,
SH

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448881/how-to-access-single-elements-in-a-table-in-r

Answer (score 0):

With `$` or indicating the "cell" in the table. There are many ways to do this.

```
library(data.table)
a <- 2
b <- 20
c <- 0.3
DT <- data.table(a, b, c)
DT
```

```
> DT
   a  b   c
1: 2 20 0.3
```

```
x <- DT$a
y <- DT$b
z <- DT$c
DT2 <- data.table(x, y, z)
DT2
```

```
> DT2
   x  y   z
1: 2 20 0.3
```

```
xa <- DT[1,1]
yb <- DT[1,2]
zc <- DT[1,3]
DT3 <- data.table(xa, yb, zc)
DT3
```

```
> DT3
   a  b   c
1: 2 20 0.3
```

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity in my question, I meant to have it done not variable by variable but for all the variables. If DT is 1 by n, I do not want to write n time the subsetting.

Comment: Given this comment and some of the comments below, I'm a bit curious about what data structure you are expecting as output.  

If your DT is 3 columns and 3 rows are you expecting the output to be 9 variables?  3 lists (or vectors) each representing a row?

If you are expecting the output to be 9 variables (in my example), it's not clear why you would need to do this.  Why not just extract the values from the DT individually when you want to consume them?

Comment: DT is a wide table (1 by n), n listed paramters: a, b, c, d.... What I expect is to extract from the data table all these parameters in R studio as values and call them as values without subsetting each time. I want to have all of them outside of the data.table, I do not want to subset them one by one doing DT$a, DT$b but I want to get all of them as values where a get value 2, b get value 20 and so on for all the n parameters. Is now a bit more clear? @bbiasi can you just subset a value one by one in a data table (basic r now-how) or can you somehow also do it? Thanks for the effort anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic R knowledge. I suggest you do a basic course (try `install.packages(swirl)`, or datacamp) and pay attention to the basic subsetting parts.

Comment: I do not mean 1 by 1, let's assume that DT is 1*50, I do not want to write it 50 times. I did not expect 3 lines of code to do such operation but one.